# $.when.apply.done not executing asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, .when

I have to execute a callback function after all the asynchronous functions finishes execution.
For that I have created an array, containing asynchronous functions:

```
var funcs = [];
var requests = [];
```

In which I have pushed some ajax functions.

This is my solution which is not working:

```
for(i = 0; i < functions.length; i++){
  var f = functions[i](); //calling each ajax functions
  requests.push(f);
}    
$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

Now functions are executing asynchronously, but the callback functions gets called before the functions execution finishes.

One of the example of ajax function I pushed :

```
functions.push(function () {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    success: function(){
    console.log("Finished execution");
  }
});
```

Comment: You should relay the promise returned by `$.ajax()` to your caller. In other words, `return $.ajax({ /* ... */ });`. Also note that the code in your question contains a syntax error.

Comment: 1. The code has errors. 2. Try adding a `console.log( "Function called" );` before `$.ajax` in the function.

Comment: The edit has fixed the fact you're not calling the functions, but you still need to do as @FrédéricHamidi suggests and return the result of `$.ajax` in your example function.

Comment: Now the functions running, but callback function gets called first, instead of at last, before all the functions finishes execution.

Comment: @rohinichaudhary please add the new code to your question (without removing the old code) so that we can see what you have now.

Comment: You need to do `return $.ajax(/*...` in your example function, rather than just `$.ajax(/*....`, as @FrédéricHamidi mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: I have not removed anything, just added little bit of code. The current code above works for asynchronous call but still `.done` method executes before they finishes

Comment: "Now functions are executing asynchronously" - No, think about it! The functions are executed *synchronously*. Each function *should* return a promise - then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anonymous function has no `return` so its effective return value is `undefined`.

So, first you need to fix your anonymous function to include a `return`:

```
functions.push(function() {
     return $.ajax(...);
});
```

You can also make a cleaner implementation of your invocation loop:

```
var requests = functions.map(function(f) {
    return f();
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(callb);
```

Comment: I have used return, still the same problem. Now ajax functions are executing. but `.done` is not.

Comment: Yeah after adding `return`, and little bit change in code, its working now. Thanks to all for helping :)